# Adding additional condition to MySQL query causes empty response

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm having a problem with MySQL query. I should select members by their age using upper and lower limit to age. For example this query returns some results

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.* 
FROM wp_users as users  
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta as mt 
ON (users.ID = mt.user_id) 
WHERE 1=1 
AND (
    (mt.meta_key LIKE 'user_birthday' AND mt.meta_value <> '' AND mt.meta_value <= 1985) 
    AND (mt.meta_key LIKE 'user_birthday' AND mt.meta_value <> '' AND mt.meta_value >= 1920)
) 
AND users.ID NOT IN (1,2,3) 
ORDER BY users.user_registered desc
```

This query retuns about 70 results. But when I add search for First name to this query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.* 
FROM wp_users as users 
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta as mt ON (users.ID = mt.user_id) 
WHERE 1=1 
AND (
    (mt.meta_key = '_upme_search_cache' AND mt.meta_value LIKE '%first_name::John%') 
    AND (mt.meta_key LIKE 'user_birthday' AND mt.meta_value <> '' AND mt.meta_value <= 1985) 
    AND (mt.meta_key LIKE 'user_birthday' AND mt.meta_value <> '' AND mt.meta_value >= 1920)
) 
AND users.ID NOT IN (1,2,3) 
ORDER BY users.user_registered desc
```

This returns 0 results, but I know I have 2 Johns in database.

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.* 
FROM wp_users as users 
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta as mt ON (users.ID = mt.user_id) 
WHERE 1=1 AND (
    (mt.meta_key = '_upme_search_cache' AND mt.meta_value LIKE '%first_name::John%')
) AND users.ID NOT IN (1,2,3) 
ORDER BY users.user_registered desc
```

This one returns 2 records.

There are certainly no syntax errors here, but I guess that my logic is off somewhere?

I should mention that this is WordPress database with UPME plugin installed.

Did I make a mistake with joining tables or something else?

Comment: can you show a sample result set?

Comment: Yes, what are the birthdays of these two Johns?

Comment: what is this `%first_name::John%`

Comment: @StaticVariable: Just a bad way to check that the first name is 'John', I guess?

Comment: It's sort of search cache that is created by UPME plugin. It's very strange and you can't search larger than and smaller than numbers

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I think he is storing  json data in database ....

Comment: @StaticVariable: Yes, something like that. Anyway, without knowing the content of the database, and the results of the query that does work, there's no real way we can answer the question.

Comment: if there is json data than i think he should use single colon `:` like `'%first_name:John%'`

Comment: Here are two queries that work, but when I combine them it returns nothing. That is what I find strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that you're querying for the data that do not reside in the same row (different values for meta_key column). You need either another JOIN to `wp_usermeta` table, or some sub-query. You can use this fiddle as an illustration of the point http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48836/2

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful..

```
$args = array(                      
        'meta_query'   => array( 'meta_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'key' => '_upme_search_cache',
                            'value' => 'first_name::John',
                            'compare' => 'LIKE'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'key' => 'user_birthday',
                            'value' => '1985',
                            'compare' => '<='
                        ),
                        array(
                            'key' => 'user_birthday',
                            'value' => '1920',
                            'compare' => '>='
                        )
                    )),
        'include'      => array(),
        'exclude'      => array(1,2,3),
        'orderby'      => user_registered ,
        'order'        =>DESC                   
     );

 $users = get_users( $args );
```

Comment: I know this should like like this, but I'm using UPME that didn't do it like this, so I can't really rewrite whole plugin :/ I was wondering if there is anything wrong with query above